# ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 5:13-30

Tags: node.js, mern, browserify

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in /Users/ravinbandara/Desktop/E-Commerce/E-Shop/frontend/node_modules/cookie-signature
```

**BREAKING CHANGE:**
webpack < 5 used to include `polyfills` for `node.js` core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

- add a fallback and install crypto-browserify

```
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
```

```
install 'crypto-browserify'
```

- If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:

```
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

I was struggling to fix this can someone help me with this. I got some bunch of errors like this same kind

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed this way ?

```
npm install crypto-browserify
```

Comment: Yes I did. It did not resolve the error. What will be the other solutions?